# Ion-list with Ion-list-header or Ion-item-divider

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've got a list of items with subgroups of items with a certain property. I want to list them in such a way that for every subgroup I've a list of the item with that property and so on, but I want that it is dynamic, if I had a new subgroup the list will be update automatically. I want to divide the subgroups with ion-list-header or ion-list-divider. I tried something like this:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let header of headers">
  <ion-list-header>
    {{ header }}
  </ion-list-header>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items | async" *ngIf="item.property === header">
    {{ item.name }}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

But I can't use `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` in the same statement and I don't want to have more than a list, I want to store all data in a single list of objects. I hope you understand what i want to do. Maybe with some pipes? Someone have some ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-container for this. Put the if condition on ng-container.

It does not interfere with the styles or layout. Read more about it here

[Ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue)

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let header of headers">
  <ng-container *ngIf="items?.length">
    <ion-list-header>
      {{ header }}
    </ion-list-header>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items | async" >
       {{ item.name }}
    </ion-item>
  </ng-container>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but in this way I visualize all the headers even when a subgroup is empty. Is there a way to avoid this too?

Comment: yes, you the ng-container for header too. use *ngif=items.length .  This way, header will only be displayed, if there is some items

Comment: Do you need any more help ?

Comment: Cuold you write here an example?

Comment: Check the updated code, now you will see header only when there are some items.

Answer (score 1):

why you don't use `virtualscroll` with `headerFn`?

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="items" [headerFn]="myHeaderFn">

  <ion-item-divider *virtualHeader="let header">
    Header: {{ header }}
  </ion-item-divider>

  <ion-item *virtualItem="let item">
    Item: {{ item }}
  </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

`headerFn` decides with `myHeaderFn` (implemented in ts file) when a header should be drawn. On long lists `virtualScroll` recycles the items so the memory is not eaten up by all the items.

See [ionic-Doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/) for details.